# Cordova background images preload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whats is the best way to make a preload function for big background images to on div.

This is my div, im using angular.js to load the images sources but some images are loading really slow.

```
<div  ng-repeat="diaporama in diaporamas">
    <div class="content-wrapper-diaporama" style="background-image: url('{{this.compose_diaporama_path(diaporama.id, diaporama.photo_file_name)}}')" />  
</div>
```